# Pass Data to childViewControllers via UISegmentControl

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift2, parameter-passing, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a parent class A having two containers B and C with two respective uiviewcontrollers. I am switching the two controllers by using a UISegmentContol. The parent class has an object "Variables" which i want to pass to UiViewControllers B and C.

My DouBt:
how do i share an object from the parent class to the two child classes?
how do i create a reference of my child classes in the parent class?

```
class A: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var segment: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet var containerSearch: UIView!
@IBOutlet var containerAdvancedSearch: UIView!
var variables: Variables?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let a = variables?.bankNameLong
    print("from " + a! + "")
}

@IBAction func actionSwitchSegments(sender: AnyObject) {
   if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.containerChangePassword.alpha = 1
            self.containerAbout.alpha = 0
        })
    } else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
            self.containerChangePassword.alpha = 0
            self.containerAbout.alpha = 1
        })
    }

}



   if segue.identifier == "segSearch"{
        let newViewController: vConSearch = segue.destinationViewController as! vConSearch
        newViewController.Variables = self.Variables
    }else if segue.identifier == "segAdvancedSearch"{
        let newViewController: vConAdvancedSearch = segue.destinationViewController as! vConAdvancedSearch
        newViewController.Variables = self.Variables
    }
```

I tried using segue but it works only for a single child controller.
But by doing segue would it not create a new instance every time i click on the UiSegmentControl.

Comment: Hey @Darth Vader could you help?

Comment: from where you are calling performSegueWithIdentifier??

Comment: from the parent class vConSettings

Comment: I dont see the code. could you please check if your prepareforsegue is getting called. Thanks

Comment: Hey @Ujjwal ..... I have updated the code.. could you take a look..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must somewhere write this code to navigate to desired viewcontroller

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segSearch", sender: sender)
```

and then the delegate

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if segue.identifier == "segSearch"{
        let newViewController: vConSearch = segue.destinationViewController as! vConSearch
        newViewController.Variables = self.Variables
    }else if segue.identifier == "segAdvancedSearch"{
        let newViewController: vConAdvancedSearch = segue.destinationViewController as! vConAdvancedSearch
        newViewController.Variables = self.Variables
    }
}
```

also put some breakpoints to debug the code if it doesn't work, to check whether the function being called and the variables are being assigned properly.